# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u25cf' in position 24: ordinal not in range(128) in Python 2.7

Tags: python

I am trying to print an `ascii` character along with `string` but I get this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u25cf' in position 24: ordinal not in range(128)

This is my `constants.ICON_BLACK_CIRCLE`

```
ICON_BLACK_CIRCLE = u'\u25CF'
```

And here I am trying to print it **with some other string**

```
print "{: ^71s}".format(constants.ICON_BLACK_CIRCLE + " - " + errormsg),    
s = "|    |"
print(s)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I could get rid of this exception.

Just make the second string also a unicode string

```
print u"{: ^71s}".format(constants.ICON_BLACK_CIRCLE + " - " +errormsg)
```